# App icon in published projects

Tags: icons, publish, smartface.io

I am having difficulties in setting my app icon for my published app.

I am using smartface app studio 4.5 I have an individual license.

I have created the right sizes for the different drawable folders using asset studio. my icon is called icon.png is that the correct name?

would appreciate some assistance on this.

Comment: in which folder you placed the icon.png file?

Comment: resources/Images/drawable.

Comment: then it should work.

Comment: just to clarify I am copying and pasting my published APK onto my android phone to see how the published output would look like. Do you think if I publish it on the store I will see my icons?

Comment: no if you can't see the icon when you run the apk on your phone you can't see it if you publish .

Comment: Ok Thanks I think the problem is in my icon resolution for my S6 cause the ico  appeared fine when i ran the ApK on my tablet

Answer (score 0):

You have to create one more folder in resources android folder here is the example

[image]

After creating this folder add all the images in this folder as well then it will work.

Comment: I have the exact same folders i will check that i have the correct spelling

Comment: I have created the folder but not luck ... my icon is 192x192

Comment: It should work if you have xxxhdpi in your data-resources-images-android folder. and icon placed in that folder